# カレンダーから入力した日付をMySQLのデータベースに保存する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

質問です。
カレンダー入力で選択した日付をデータベースに登録したいのですが、うまく行きません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
params内にあるdue_onというキーです。

データベース上のreportsテーブルにdue_onというカラムに入れたいのですが、型はdateで合っているのでしょうか？[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

string型かなとも思ったのですが、どなたか分かる方教えていただきますか？

viewのコード (haml)

```
    = form_with model: @report, html: {class: "Report"}, local: true do |f|
      %ul.Report__contents
        %li= date_field_tag :due_on, Date.today, use_month_numbers: true
        %li= f.collection_select :job_id, Job.all, :id, :job, include_blank: "内容を選択して下さい"
        %li= f.collection_select :hour_id, Hour.all, :id, :hour, include_blank: "時間を選択して下さい"
        %p 時間
        %li= f.text_field :impression, class: 'Report__imp', placeholder: '改善点'
      = f.submit '保存する', class: 'Report__submit'
```

コントローラーのコード

```
params.require(:report).permit(:due_on, :job_id, :hour_id, :impression).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/272671

Answer (score 1):

おそらく
date_field_tag を f.date_field
にかえればいいのではないかと思いますが
それでだめならコントローラ全文を表示してください

Comment: f.date_fieldに変えて他も少し変更したら登録ができました。
結局dateカラムのdate型でうまくいきました。
助かりました、ありがとうございます！